# how to display validation errors on submit with Formik?

Tags: formik

Very weird thing that Formik seems to be so famous but I can't find this very simple functionnality.

Lets say the user try to send the form with an empty field, how can I display the errors ? I can display them once the field is touched but not once the form has been sent (and obviously I don't want to display the errors right away, for example an empty field)

The actual behavior is that the submit function is not called if the validation fails, seems right but what about error display ? It seems there is no simple way to do this (I found a few kinda heavy work around with some callbacks and handler components but what's the point using a form library then...) 
So maybe I have missed something please tell me

Any idea how to display the validation errors when submitting the form ?

Comment: Take a look at this..if you are still stacked https://stackoverflow.com/q/67606619/5220683